# How to limit width of column in p:dataTable, w/o line break, keeping single line?

Tags: primefaces

I have been having hard time with Primefaces and SO is my ultimate place to find answer for issues.

I have `p:dataTable` with many columns so each of them should have short width. For headers, they seem OK but for data columns they break to 2 or more lines which I don't prefer.

I made first column's width larger to show what are in data table. Header text is fine, keeping it to single line. But data columns are bad for me. I prefer they keep it to single line. I want no line break. Ellipses is preferable but not mandatory.

```xml
<p:dataTable id="searchResultTable" var="searchData" value="#{registerBean.searchDataList}"
        scrollHeight="200"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        rowKey="#{searchData.model}"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{registerBean.selectedSearchData}"
        paginator="true" rows="10"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20" resizableColumns="true">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{registerBean.onSelectedSearchData}"/>
    <p:column headerText="#{registerBean.getSearchResultHeaderText(0)}"
              width="30" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerBean.getSearchResultText(rowIndex,0)}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{registerBean.getSearchResultHeaderText(1)}"
              width="30" style="10px; height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerBean.getSearchResultText(rowIndex,1)}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{registerBean.getSearchResultHeaderText(2)}"
              width="30" style="10px; height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
        <h:outputText value="#{registerBean.getSearchResultText(rowIndex,2)}" />
    </p:column>
```

I used `h:outputText` for each columns. I don't persist to `h:outputText`, any component I can use with Primefaces can be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: @BestPractices I use Primefaces 3.3.1.

Comment: if you don't want linebreaks, then how do you want the text to be displayed? do you want it to be trimmed?

Comment: @Damian Just like you see on header. Simple cut is OK, adding ellipses seems better.

Comment: what do you mean by ellipses?

Comment: @Damian When space is shorter than text to display, cutting text and adding ... at the end of shorten text to tell user there is more to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could find a solution. Adding CSS shown below to `<p:column/>` worked for me. Ellipsis is not working but no line-feeding, no expanding line height.

```
<style type="text/css">
.singleLine
{
    text-wrap:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
</style>
```

And do like this:

```
<p:column headerText="Something"
    width="100" styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
    <h:outputText value="#{something.value}" />
</p:column>
```

I hope it will help few people on this globe.